# mdb's substitute for gdb's catch throw?

Tags: gdb, solaris, mdbg

I am not very much expert in gdb and mdb but What i know is that :-

```
      `(gdb) catch throw`
```

This will interrupt anytime an exception is thrown
   Do i have any similar command in mdb which will  interrupt anytime an exception is thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this doesn't exist as such; that's because on Solaris, it depends on your compiler and/or compile options which C++ ABI is being used (and how exceptions are being thrown).

`mdb` isn't making an attempt to know all of that, and neither is `gdb` on Solaris (if you compile it, `catch throw` will not work with either old- or new-style Sun CC binaries).

Your best option is to figure out what the "C++ ABI hooks" are, i.e. which hidden / internal functions are being called on `throw()`, and breakpoint those. Or, once you have found / enumerated those hooks, write your own module that'd implement a `::catch` command (`mdb` is extensible - *modular* debugger).

**Edit:** (shameless plug) see also [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9600391/512360) (regarding C++ exceptions and DTrace; the "hidden" function names there can be used for `mdb` breakpoints as well).